# mysql - adding datetime column and inserting values referenced on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

i have a 'results' table that has a datetime colum 'created_time'. 
this table reference another table 'results_values' (results.id reference results_values.results_id). here are tables describe:

```
mysql> describe webforms_results;
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| webform_id       | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| store_id         | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_id      | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| customer_ip      | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_time     | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| update_time      | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| approved         | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| view_on_frontend | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


mysql> describe webforms_results_values;
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| result_id    | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| field_id     | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value        | text     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rating       | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_time | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

now i've added a datetime column 'created_time' on 'results_values', and i want to insert datetimes on the second tables copying them from the first table on the corresponding id. is there a quick way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes triggers are the solution. And if you want to update already inserted data, you can do :

```
UPDATE webforms_results_values wrv INNER JOIN webforms_results wr
ON wrv.result_id = wr.id
SET wrv.created_time = wr.created_time
```

Answer (score 1):

Create "Triggers" to update each and every update of those tables.

Please refer following URL:
[Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)